# Controlling Single Masonry Item Position

Tags: jquery-masonry

I'm using masonry layout in WordPress so my local site's masonry layout is put together with loops. I've created a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WebEnvelopment/DD6g2/)** to explain my question.

**How do I control the positioning of one item within a masonry layout?**

I want a div to always be at the top right of the masonry container (to the right of my top left corner stamp)

**How do I override the positioning that masonry assigns its .box items?**

```
#container { max-width:635px; width:100%; }
.corner-stamp { background:gray;  width: 90px; height: 90px; }

.box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #6AD;
  float: left;
}

/* I want to freely position this item with css */
#biggerBlock{ 
  width: 395px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #6AD;
  left:25%; /* overidden by masonry */
}

.box.large {
  background: #084;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

UPDATE:

David Desandro answered the question on the [official Masonry](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/530#issuecomment-23132536) Git page. The new isotope v2 will have this feature with the ability to include 2 corner-stamps. Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `cornerStampSelector` property in pure masonry now. You can use `stamp` option:

> Specifies which elements are stamped within the layout. These are
>   special layout elements which will not be laid out by Masonry. Rather,
>   Masonry will layout item elements *below* stamped elements.

```
$container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 100,
    animate: true,
    stamp: '#biggerBlock'
  });
```

And `stamp` method:

> Stamp the elements in the layout. Masonry will lay out item elements
>   *around* stamped elements.

```
$container.masonry('stamp',$('#biggerBlock'));
```

Comment: Is that different from cornerStampSelector: used in my fiddle? Care to fork my fiddle and show me your skills?

Comment: Yes, it is. In your jsfiddle you are using stand alone Masonry library. And you need specify another property to stamp an element. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bqEx/1).

Comment: Sorry for some reason I wasn't getting the obvious. Great answer!